# Api con Spring con varias tablas en la base de datos

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

mi problema es que no se como agregar una agregar un nuevo elemento en una relacion ManyToOne bidericional.

Esta es la clase controlador, desde donde se responde, quiero darle el ID de una Gateway y crear un Device.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/gateway")
public class GatewayController {

@Autowired()
GatewayServiceImpl gatewayService;
DeviceServiceImpl deviceServiceImpl;

@GetMapping("/")
public ArrayList<Gateway> getGateway() {
    return gatewayService.getGateway();
}

@PostMapping("/")
public Gateway saveGateway(@RequestBody Gateway gateway) {
    return this.gatewayService.saveGateway(gateway);

}

@PostMapping("/{id}")
public void addDevice(@RequestBody Device device){
    gatewayService.saveDevice(device);
}
```

Esta es la clase de implementacion, no estoy seguro de que este correcto.

```
@Service
public class GatewayServiceImpl implements GatewayService {

private Gateway gateway;

@Autowired
GatewaysRepository gatewaysRepository;

@Override
public ArrayList<Gateway> getGateway() {
    return (ArrayList<Gateway>) gatewaysRepository.findAll();
}

@Override
public Gateway saveGateway(Gateway gateway) {
    return gatewaysRepository.save(gateway);
}

public void saveDevice(Device device) {
    gateway.saveDevice(device);
}
```

Y este es el método al que llama.

```
    public void saveDevice(Device thedevice) {

       if (devices == null) {
        devices = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        devices.add(thedevice);

        thedevice.setGateway(this);
        }
    }
```

En resumen, quiero entender como es el mecanismo para crear un nuevo Device, del Gateway.

Comment: en ningún momento estás usando jpa, será por eso que no entiendes el mecanismo?

Comment: Si... debe ser... he estado leyendo sobre el tema para documentarme... porque tengo un error que me perciste

Comment: y ese error que dice textualmente?